# Consistency of Martin-Löf Type Theory and Categorical Models

Tags: logic, reference-request, type-theory

Having read the parts of the hott book that introduce intuitionistic type theory (+univalence), I want to continue by studying some meta theory. I'm particularly interested in strategies for proving consistency of (not necessarily univalent) type theories but I couldn't find any introductory text book covering the subject.

As far as I can tell, the usual approach seems to be to find some set theoretic model using category theory, interpret the formulae/contexts of the type theory in the model category and prove that all deduction rules are satisifed in the model category (i.e. if there is an object $X$ in the model category $C$ whose existence is interpreted as validity of a formula $\phi$ of the type theory and there is rule that lets us conclude $\psi$ from $\phi$, there is an object $Y \in C$ that is interpreted as truth of $\psi$).

Is there a paper or a sequence of papers that introduce the technique rigorously without requiring much prior knowledge of the subject? I am familiar with some basic notions of category theory (adjunctions, limits, sheaves, sites, etc.).

I found [these slides](http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/hottseminar2012/05categories.pdf) by Shulman and [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.3456v1.pdf) by Clairambault and Dybjer that seem to be relevant. Is there other material I may be interested in?

I'm also happy to learn about other approaches. For example, in [this paper](http://www.ioc.ee/~james/papers/lfmtp08_jmc.pdf), Chapman works towards 'dogfooding' type theory, i.e. interpreting (probably some weaker form of) it in itself (thus, proving consistency). Is there any news on this front?

Comment: You could read the Kapulkin–Lumsdaine–Voevodsky paper about the model of univalent foundations in $\mathbf{sSet}$. The more recent Lumsdaine–Warren paper on local universes may also be helpful.